# How to catch the error on screen into variable in TCL using catch

Tags: error-handling, tcl, catch-block

To grep the error on the screen though catch eg

```
   puts $c
   #error on terminal : can't read "c": no such variable

   catch {puts $c} err
   puts $err # value of err 1
```

Is there any way to catch actual error message in 
TCL apart from signal in variable err.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Read the `::errorInfo` or `::errorCode` global variables to get the stack trace and a machine-parsable "POSIX error" three-element list, correspondingly.

Since Tcl 8.5, it's also possible to pass a name of a dictionary to `catch` after the name of the variable to receive the result, and that dictionary will be populated by much of what can be obtained via "classic" error variables I described above, and more.

This is all explained in [the `catch` manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm).

Comment: In tcl 8.6 you even got the [`try`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm) command, which can also be useful. The usage of `try` is easier than it looks (the usual `try {...} on error msg {puts $msg}`). Also note that Tcl builds unlike Java or .Net the error stack while unwinding.